# Html form - reviewing and changing information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a type of checkout page that asks users for their payment information, then they click on a Review button which takes them to a new "panel" to review all their information which they can then go back and change if needed, this has to happen in the same page, so I have an "information-panel" div that changes to "information-review-panel" via jquery once the button is clicked, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        //Save values from the form fields
        var fn = $("#first_name").val() + " " + $("#last_name").val();
        var cc = $("#credit_card").val();
        
        //Switch panels
        $("div.information-panel").replaceWith($("div.information-review-panel"));
        $("div.information-review-panel").fadeIn(1000);
      
        //Place values in the new panel
        $("#review-name").html(fn);
        $("#review-card").html(cc);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="information-panel">
  <div class="form-line">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="credit_card">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="credit_card" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step_nav">
    <input type="submit" class="blue-button next" value="review">
</div>


<div class="information-review-panel">
  <h2>Review Panel</h2>
  <h4>Please review your information below:</h4>
  <div class="amount">
    <h3>
       <b>Name:</b><span id="review-name"></span> 
    </h3>
    <h3>
       <b>Credit Card Number:</b><span id="review-card"></span> 
    </h3>
  </div>
```

As you can see my first issue is that the Review button actually submits the form, this is because it's the only way I know of validating the information on the form, but obviously I don't want to submit the form before reviewing it and being able to go back to edit any info. So my question would be, how can I move back and forth between the two panels and validate the data on the form without actually submitting the form? I'm not sure if AngularJS is an option but I can't use it for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to submit the form when you click on review, instead show submit button in review panel.

**check this https://jsfiddle.net/MrDahdoul/mvq0w8t9/61/**

```
<div class="alert">Fill all fields</div>
<div class="information-panel">
  <div class="form-line">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="credit_card">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="credit_card" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="step_nav">
  <button id="review" class="blue-button next">Review</button>
</div>


<div class="information-review-panel">
  <h2>Review Panel</h2>
  <h4>Please review your information below:</h4>
  <div class="amount">
    <h3>
       <b>Name:</b><span id="review-name"></span> 
    </h3>
    <h3>
       <b>Credit Card Number:</b><span id="review-card"></span> 
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div id="step_nav_rev">
    <button id="back" class="blue-button next">Back</button>
    <input type="submit" class="blue-button next" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#review").click(function() {
    var first = $("#first_name").val();
    var last = $("#last_name").val();
    var card = $("#credit_card").val();
    if (first.trim() == '' || last.trim() == '' || card.trim() == '') {
      $(".alert").show();
    } else {
      $(".alert").hide();
      $(".information-panel").fadeOut();
      $(".information-review-panel").fadeIn();
      $(this).fadeOut();
      $("#review-name").text(first + " " + last);
      $("#review-card").text(card);
    }
  });

  $("#back").click(function() {
    $(".information-panel, #review").fadeIn();
    $(".information-review-panel").fadeOut();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this works, thank you. my only issue now is that when I move to the review panel, the information in the form is not validated. for example, first name/last name/credit card fields are all required, but clicking on the Review button lets the user move forward without asking them to fill out these fields first. How can i validate the information in the form when moving from information-panel to information-review-panel?

Comment: Check input on click if empty and trim white spaces, for example `if(first.trim() == '' ){ alert('field is required'); }` I updated answer's link, please check. for advanced validation use Jquery Validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a probable solution to your review button submitting the form would be preventing the default action of the button. I.E., instead of having the panel appear on **submit**, have an on-click function for the review button that has the **event** as a parameter, then you could simply do `event.preventDefault();` in order to stop the normal function of the submit button and bring up the new panel.

On the new panel, you could then have a new button that submits the actual information, or a button that allows them to edit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace those lines:

This one :

```
<input type="submit" class="blue-button next" value="review">
```

By this:

```
<input type="button" id="modifyInputs" class="blue-button next" value="review">
```

And this one:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
```

By this:

```
$("#modifyInputs").click(function () {
```

Then, at the end of this function... Maybe do `$("form").submit();`.

Comment: yes I see my mistake now, thank you. This works and I am able to move back and forth between the two panels, my only issue is that since I am no longer submitting the form when I click on the review button, the user is able to move to the next panel without having to fill out any "required" fields, how can I validate the information in the form without actually submitting it?